# Efficient 8-bits and 16-bits computations in OCaml

Tags: bit-manipulation, ocaml

I am currently working on a project in OCaml where I have to manipulate unsigned integers on 8 bits and on 16 bits. In my context, things can get a little messy, I sometimes want to convert an 8 bit integer into a 16 bits one, or split a 16 bits integer into two 8 bits one. I also want to use all the operations like addition, or the bitwise operations on those. Since there are all these interaction between 8 and 16 bits, I really like the comfort of having separate types for those. However, I still want my program to compute reasonnably efficiently, and I don't want to actually lose too much time casting an integer of a given size into another size. So my question is essentially how should I go about this? I have two main options but I don't know enough about the low-level interpretation of OCaml to comfortably chose:

#### Option 1 : Use dedicated types

I figured that I can use the Stdint library that is available through opam and has an implementation of the types `uint8` and `uint16` which are exactly what I am looking for.

Pros

I get very good mileage from the typing and will definitely avoid silly bugs from this

Cons

I have to constantly use the functions `Uint8.to_uint16` and `Uint16.to_uint8`, which might eventually add up to heavy memory usage and poor efficiency of the compiled program, depending on how the precise representation is stored in machine

#### Option 2 : Encode everything within the type `int`

This means that all my integers will simply be of type `int` and I will have to program the addition of two 8-bits integers and of two 16-bits integers in this type, for instance.

Pros:

I think these operations can be programmed in a very efficient way using usual operations and the bitwise operations on the type `int`.

Cons:

I get essentially nothing from the typing and I have to trust myself to chose the right function at the right time.

#### Possible workaround

I could use two modules for defining 8-bits and 16-bits integers encoded in an `int` declared as private. I think that would essentially work like I presented with Option 2. The fact that I chose the type to be private would however mean that I cannot switch from one to the other without running into a typing mistake, thus forcing explicit casts and getting leverage from the type system. Still I expect the casts to be very efficient, since the memory representation of the object won't change.

So I would like to know how you would go about that? Is it worth going through all the trouble, do you think a solution is clearly better, or are they reasonably equivalent?

#### Bonus

Everytime I want to print (in hexadecimal) the value of a variable `a` of type `uint8`, I am writing

```
Printf.ksprintf "a = %02x" (Uint8.to_int a)
```

There is again a cast that seems to me a bit silly, I could also use direclty the `Uint8.to_string_hex` function, but it writes explicitly the `0x` in front of the number, which I don't want. Ideally I would like to just write

```
Printf.ksprintf "a = %02x" (Uint8.to_int a)
```

Is there a way to change the scopes and do some magic with the Printf to make it happen?

Comment: You might be underestimating the time you need to implement it properly. The library exists, is tested, portable, etc. Plus it looks implemented in a way that is not far from what you are describing as a workaround. But I don't know, honestly I just had a quick look at the code (https://github.com/andrenth/ocaml-stdint), maybe there are some things that can be improved, Feel free to have a look and think a bit more about it before starting coding your own solution.

Comment: I would probably go for the first approach and only worry about the conversions if the program was slow and profiling showed them to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I started doing, but I got scared by the number of conversions. I wanted to know if there was a good heuristic as to if it was really expensive or not, but using the profiler if needed to check in my case seems like a good point

Answer (score 3):

In the stdint library both int8 and int16 are represented as `int` so there is no real tradeoff between option 1 and option 2,

```
type int8 = private int
(** Signed 8-bit integer *)

type int16 = private int
(** Signed 16-bit integer *)
```

The `stdint` library already provides you the best of two worlds, you have an efficient implementation and type safety. Yes, you need to do these translations but they no-ops and there only for the typechecker.

Also, if you're looking for modular arithmetic (and, in general, modeling machine words and bitvectors) then you can look at our [Bitvec](https://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/master/bitvec/Bitvec/index.html) library, which we developed as part of the [Binary Analysis Platform](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap). It is focused on performance while still providing type safety and a lot of operations. We modeled it based on the latest SMT-LIB specification to give clear semantics to all operations. It uses the excellent [Zarith](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith) library underneath the hood that enables efficient representation for small and arbitrary-length integers.

Since the modularity is not a property of a bitvector itself, but a property of an operation we do not encode the number of bits in the type and use the same type (and representation) for all bitvectors from 1-bits to thousands-of-bits. However, it is impossible to use mix-match the types incorrectly. E.g., you can use generic functions,

```
(x + y) mod m8
```

Or predefined modules for the specified modulus, e.g.,

```
M8.(x + y)
```

The library has a minimal number of dependencies, so try it by installing

```
opam install bitvec
```

There are also additional libraries like `bitvec-order`, `bitvec-sexp`, and `bitvec-order` that enable further integration with the Core suite of libraries, if you need them.